# Prevent android button from being pressed many times

Tags: android, button, sdk

I tried `Thread.sleep(x)` and I tried

```
setEnabled(false);
setClickable(false);
```

But neither worked as expected. I read somewhere that the clicks are queued and therefore the previous solutions didn't worked.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could set a flag in your onClick, something like `clickable = false` once it's been clicked once, and then re-enable it when you want. Run the relevant onClick code only if `clickable` is `true`.

Comment: Thanks, I used something like that (I used time check)

Answer (score 1):

You could disable it once clicked. add in the xml a listner for the on click

```
<Button
   android:id="@+id/button1"
   android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
   android:layout_width ="wrap_content"
   android:text = "lets do this"
   android:onClick = "DoIt"
/>
```

And then disable it within the on click listner

```
public void DoIt(View v){
    ((Button) v).setEnabled(false);

    ...your code...
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work. The clicks are queued. So if the user clicks 3 times quickly, there are 3 calls to the `DoIt()` method queued. Once the first call gets executed, the button will be disabled, but by then it is too late and the other 2 calls to `DoIt()` will still occur.

Comment: @DavidWasser sorry for late comment. But perhaps you didn't put the line of code in the right place.

Comment: @Cԃաԃ No. It makes no difference where you put that line of code. Disabling a button in the `onClick()` method is not reliable, because the Android framework queues the button click events in an event queue. `onClick()` methods are not called synchronously when the user clicks the button. Therefore, if the user is quick enough (or the device is slow enough), it is always possible to get multiple **click** events in the queue before the first `onClick()` method is called.

Comment: @DavidWasser, I was just curious about it as I use it in my apps. Thanks for explaining, I have not yet faced this issue myself, but it is always good to learn. I also used the old trick with -if-else-boolean combo, but I guess it has the same effect.